# Return Twitter's Future within a certain duration

Tags: java, finagle, twitter-util

According to Twitter Util's Future documentation, Future[.within()](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/util/Future.html#within(timer:com.twitter.util.Timer,timeout:com.twitter.util.Duration,exc:=%3EThrowable):com.twitter.util.Future%5BA%5D) or [.by()](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/util/Future.html#by(timer:com.twitter.util.Timer,when:com.twitter.util.Time,exc:=%3EThrowable):com.twitter.util.Future%5BA%5D) "Returns a new Future that fails if it is not satisfied before the given time".

I was trying to use this, in Java, to return a (Future) String if getDownload() takes less than 5 secs, and return / throw an exception if getDownload() takes more than 5 seconds.

```
Future<String> futureDownload = getDownload();
return futureDownload.within(DefaultTimer.twitter(), Duration.fromSeconds(5));
```

I cannot get it to work. If getDownload() takes, for example, 15 secs, it returns after 15 secs.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you should use [Await.result](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/util/Await$.html#result%5BT%5D(awaitable:com.twitter.util.Awaitable%5BT%5D,timeout:com.twitter.util.Duration):) instead.

Example:

```
Await.result(future, Duration#fromSeconds);
```

Comment: I was trying to not use Await.result inside my function. But I was using Await.result in the calling function, and it worked. Thanks